# Kivy execute function when widget is dragged

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

I have a little demo here:

> From `DemoApp.py`:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix.behaviors import DragBehavior
from kivy.core.window import Window


class DraggableButton(DragBehavior, Button):
    def on_drag(self, *args):
        ...


class DemoLayout(FloatLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(DemoLayout, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.add_widget(DraggableButton(text='Drag Me'))


class DemoApp(App):
    def build(self):
        self.button= DraggableButton(text='Drag Me')
        Window.bind(mouse_pos=lambda w, p: setattr(self.button, "mouse_pos", p))
        return self.button


if __name__ == '__main__':
    DemoApp().run()
```

> From `demo.kv`:

```
<DraggableButton>:
    drag_rectangle: self.x, self.y, self.width, self.height
    drag_timeout: 10000000
    drag_distance: 0
```

The problem is, I want to call my `on_drag` method when the `DraggableButton` is dragged.

Also, I only want the mouse position while in the function, so I can remove the line 
`Window.bind(mouse_pos=lambda w, p: setattr(self.button, "mouse_pos", p))`

Is there any solution to this?

Comment: and what is the problem? Do you get error message? Did you try to use `print()` in `on_drag()` to see if it works? Did you check what you get in args in `on_draw()` ? Maybe it gives mouse positon so you don't need `bind()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It uses `DragBehavior` so I found source code for [DragBehavior](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/_modules/kivy/uix/behaviors/drag.html)
and I see it has method `on_touch_move(touch)`.

I replaced this method in `DraggableButton()` and when button is moved then it gets `MouseMotionEvent` with `pos` which seems to be mouse position.

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix.behaviors import DragBehavior
from kivy.core.window import Window


class DraggableButton(DragBehavior, Button):
    def on_touch_move(self, touch):  
        super().on_touch_move(touch)  # run original `on_touch_move()`
        
        print('[on_drag] touch:', touch)
        
        #print('[on_drag] touch.dpos:', touch.dpos)
        #print('[on_drag] touch.spos:', touch.spos)
        print('[on_drag] touch.pos:', touch.pos)

        print('---')


class DemoApp(App):
    def build(self):
        self.button = DraggableButton(text='Drag Me')
        return self.button


if __name__ == '__main__':
    DemoApp().run()
```

Result:

```
[on_drag] touch: <MouseMotionEvent spos=(0.36, 0.5766666666666667) pos=(288.0, 346.0)>
[on_drag] touch.pos: (288.0, 346.0)
---
[on_drag] touch: <MouseMotionEvent spos=(0.35875, 0.5783333333333334) pos=(287.0, 347.0)>
[on_drag] touch.pos: (287.0, 347.0)
---
[on_drag] touch: <MouseMotionEvent spos=(0.35875, 0.5783333333333334) pos=(287.0, 347.0)>
[on_drag] touch.pos: (287.0, 347.0)
---
```